# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - 403 error on ajax call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting a 403 error on my site on an ajax call. my site is hosted on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. I have full access to the log files (i.e. eb logs -a). Which file would contain info on this 403 error?

I've got access to these files in var/log/

[image]

Thanks

Comment: check nginx files.

Comment: No idea where those would be located. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Just go to EB console, and there in `Logs` menu you can download full sets of logs. Alternatively, ssh to the instnace and check in `/var/log`

Comment: I've got access to these log files in /var/log/, but I'm not sure which one is related to nginx. (i'll update my post with the list)

Comment: look by name. it could be folder `nginx` as well.

Comment: Check `httpd`. Is seems you are using apache, not nginx.

Comment: Thanks. Checked the two files in that folder. The 403 doesn't come up. Thanks though.